# C++ SetProcessAffinityMask use all processors

Tags: c++, process

I want to set process to use all processors.  I tried

```
SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);
```

but it doesn't set to all processors.

Comment: Use GetLastError to retrieve any errror code if SetProcessAffinityMask fails. Does your process spawn multiple threads? If yes then you can use SetThreadAffinityMask with a thread handle to target a specific core instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the Microsoft documentation for [SetProcessAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx) you'll see that you need to specify a `1` bit to enable running on that processor.  The call you're making would not allow your process to run on any CPU, so this is probably being rejected.  Check the return value of your `SetProcessAffinityMask` call and then call `GetLastError` if necessary to find out why.

A new process is set to run on all CPUs so you shouldn't need to call this function to specify that, unless your process was spawned by another one that wants to restrict this for reasons of its own.

There are also considerations when running on a system with more than 64 CPUs.